# Laravel: How to get relational model from 2D array of IDs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have an array of ids `$bookingPaymentPending[attendee_id][program_id] =`

```
array(2) { [416]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(4) } 
           [417]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(4) } }
```

I want to get the collection of relational models for an `attendee` and their `programs`. Basically I want to access `$attendee->programs`

I do this....

```
foreach ($bookingsPaymentPending as $attendee_id => $program_ids)
{
  $attendees[$attendee_id] = Attendee::find($attendee_id)->with(['scheduled_programs' => function($q) use ($program_ids)
  {
    $q->whereIn('id', $program_ids);
  }]);
}
```

But `$attendees` isn't right because I didn't know how to put it into an eloquent model. Can someone show me how to do this properly? Is there a simple eloquent way to do this? or is query builder the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that give you the expected output?

```
$attendees = Attendee::with('scheduled_programs')
    ->whereIn('id', array_keys($bookingPaymentPending))
    ->get();

foreach($attendees as $attendee){
    var_dump($attendee->scheduled_programs);
}
```